# Thor Gem - Sending parameter prior to task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thor

Confusing description I know please see example:

```
Foo < Thor

  desc "bar","bar method"
  def bar
    puts "Hello from bar #{options[:id]}"
  end

  desc "nar","nar method"
  def nar
    puts "Hello from nar"
  end
end
```

This is pretty straight forward. So if I call (thor has been setup this way to use class name as first identifier). There is no id now so nothing is printed.

```
foo bar
> Hello from bar
foo nar
> Hello from nar
```

And finally the question, how can I use Thor to be able to send parameter to method in this form?

```
foo 12 bar
> Hello from bar 12
foo nar 
> Hello from nar
```

What I am trying to do is pass parameter bar prior to task name, is this possible with Thor?

Sorry for confusing question, but best way to simplify my complicated code at the moment.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way for the task name not to be the first parameter in Thor.  Is that the requirement that you're trying to solve, or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have the power of Ruby so you can:

```
class Foo < Thor
  desc "bar","bar method"
  def bar(id)
    puts "Hello from bar #{id}"
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    if m.is_a? Integer  ## Might not work. May need to_i and an exception check.
      bar(m)
    end
  end
end
```

This is off the top of my head, so your mileage may vary...